# Why do my nodes look different specifically the math node and the value node?

Tags: node-editor, shader-nodes

[image]

I am trying to copy a node setup (left) however I cant get it the same (mine is the right)

1. The Value node looks different on my end (
2. The Math node (divide) looks different  on my end because there is no input titled colour

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hello and welcome. what version of Blender are you using?. 1 You mean the name of the value node? 2. Are you sure is a math node? looks to me that is a Mix node (mix RGB in older versions)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Im using 3.3.1
1. Is that the only difference
2. ahhh this makes way more sense thank you!!!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the value node, sorry.

Comment: If you're talking about the name of the value nodes, remember you can right click any node and rename it - That's why the names are different.

Comment: On the left side is a Mix RGB node (since 3.4 it would be a Mix node in Color mode), on the right is a Math node.

Answer (score 2):

The two nodes you have are respectively a Mix RGB node and a Math node, which can be respectively found under the Color and Converter categories.

Since Blender v3.4, the Mix RGB node has been reworked into the Mix node, which can support multiple data types (Color, Float and Vector). It's basically the Mix RGB with extra options.

[image: Nodes]

Important note:
Because of the difference, files created with v3.4 cannot be open with an older version of Blender. Opening old files with 3.4 and up will have the Mix RGB nodes automatically converted into the new Mix node.